# Why I'm getting theme related error when trying to add external JS to form?

Tags: forms, 8, javascript

I'm trying to add Google Map API to node form:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mm_form_node_foo_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'google/maps';
}
```

Library config (mm.libraries.yml in module root directory):

```
google.maps:
  js:
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap: {type: external, attributes: { defer: true, async: true, data-test: map-link } } }
```

and the error is:

> User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system:
>   google in drupal_get_filename() (line 234 of
>   core/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add the module/theme name before the attached library:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mm/google.maps';
```

Otherwise drupal is looking for google as your module/theme name.

Comment: Indeed thanks, error disappeared but it seems google maps isn't loaded (no script tag with this)

Comment: Do you get more errors? There should be at least one, because you have 2x `{` and 3x `}` in *.libraries.yml.

Comment: Shouldn't you encode those URL parameters?

Comment: @4k4 now I have 2x{ and 2x}, still not working, got error: google is not defined...strange that I didn't get exception about YAML syntax

Comment: @cilefen IMO it seems to be ok, I based on https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

Comment: @cilefen you are right, I have &amp; instead of & in page source, please add your hint as an answer here

Comment: @drupality, shouldn't be this another question? You asked about why you are getting a theme related error.

Comment: @4k4 right, I'll ask another question in my spare time, now I have a lot of different troubles with gmap api anyway